# who coined the prime ideals?

Tags: math-history

I know that Ernst Kummer first made used of "ideal complex numbers", and, hinging on that, Dedekind later introduced his "ideals" in Vorlesungen über Zahlentheorie. But, who coined the term "prime ideal"? Kummer? Dedekind? I would appreciate a specific reference to the work where they appear (a definition would be great).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is Dedekind, in his $1871$'s paper *Vorlesungen über Zahlentheorie von P.G. Lejeune Dirichlet* who defines it : an ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ distinct from  $\mathfrak{o}$ (ring of integers of a number field, as far as I remember the paper) and that has no other divisors that $\mathfrak{o}$ and $\mathfrak{p}$ is called a prime ideal. Bourbaki (in the historical notes to *Algèbre* or *Algèbre commutative*) mentions and confirms this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Did Kummer have some analogous concept to prime ideal from which Dedekind coul elaborate, or did Dedekind create it out f the blue, so to speak?

Comment: Actually, as far as I remember, Kummer was interested in finding a notion fixing unique factorization in number rings, and he therefore had to introduce certain *ideal numbers.* It is Dedekind who later later translated these ideas in terms of ideals. Prime integers where known at that time (as they were known since Euclide) and prime elements in rings of integers were called prime because of the analogy with prime numbers. This led I think to call principal ideals which generated by a prime prime ideals, and led to prime ideal.

Comment: one stupid question: you wrote zero, or the letter ou? I assume it is the letter O and you want to refer to the ring of integers with it......am I right?

Comment: It's the whole ring of integers indeed.

Comment: so it is a letter O, in italic, sort of, right?

Comment: No, it's a gothic big o.

Comment: Thanks....I not sure, though, what it is meant by O as a divisor there. I mean, accepting the prime can have O as a divisor could mean he hast a long series of integers as factors, or do i miss something?